# Programmatic refresh of static files in STS workspace has not effect in Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

My **spring boot** project uses the frontend-maven-plugin to trigger a gulp build of some static js/html files when they are edited in STS. The output is written to `src/main/resources/static` and shall be served by Tomcat during development.

When the gulp build process is complete, the frontend-maven-plugin triggers a refresh on the output directory causing STS to reload the updated files. This works as intended and modifications are directly visible in the editor if a modified file was loaded.

Modifications are however not noticed by the web server and unmodified files are served to the browser. A manual refresh of the workspace following the reload by the frontend-maven-plugin does not work either.

The only solution so far has been to disable the automatic reload of the output directory by the frontend-maven-plugin. If modifications of files in the resources directory are noticed by a manual workspace refresh then the web server serves the modified files.

Is there a way to trigger a refresh when a workspace file is changed? The programmatic refresh does not cause the same effect as a manual refersh of the workspace.

Comment: Did you take a look at the reload options that you can define in the server editor (in the "Application Reload Behavior" section)? Maybe that helps. I would also recommend to take a look at the Spring Boot Devtools, which can help with reload behavior in a very nice way (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html)

Comment: and with regards to the workspace refresh, there are options to let Eclipse/STS automatically trigger a refresh of the workspace files is something changes. Did you try that? Does that help in your situation?

Comment: I could not find any server reload settings. Maybe that is because I'm using the embedded webserver of Spring Boot. Spring Boot Devtools are enabled and the reload when classes are changed works fine.

Comment: Enabling the workspace refresh settings to "Refresh using native hooks or polling" helped. Now Eclipse detects changes to the static files and Tomcat delivers them. 
Still when Eclipse is triggered to reload the specific directory, the workspace refresh setting does not have any effect. This maybe because Eclipse does not trigger a webserver refresh on file changes it has been informed about by m2e.
The changed workspace refresh setting helps a lot in the development workflow. Thanks!